# Filtering out words having only 1 letter

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please help me to understand how extract only words with length greater than 1?

```
WORD
TPI is a new program
as E stands for Eimear
your are using an extra L
```

The code below select upper case words/letters :

```
dt['WORD'].str.extractall(r'([A-Z]+)')
```

The problem is that I would like only filter letters with more than one (TPI) and not (TPI, E, L).

How can I get these words (TPI)?

Comment: This is a generic regular-expression issue not pandas, please read the Python [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). `[A-Z]+` is a regex that matches 1+ capital letters. But you wanted a regex that matches 2+ capital letters, which is `[A-Z]{2,}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `findall`

```
df.WORD.str.findall(r'([A-Z]{2,})')
Out[120]: 
0    [TPI]
1       []
2       []
Name: WORD, dtype: object
```

Comment: @LucaDiMauro I am fixing it now ~

Comment: @LucaDiMauro so you want all upper case words ?

Comment: yes. Unfortunately my code is selecting also single letter (E, L) and I would like to exclude them. Just keeping only upper case words with length greater than 1

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it -- assuming `list_of_words` is where you start from:

```
list_of_words = ['TPI', 'E', 'L']

filtered_list_without_single_character_words = [w for w in list_of_words if len(w) > 1]
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. Unfortunately it may happen to have thousands of words, so I could not know which word to exclude or select

Comment: Apply the filter after you have already extracted the list of words. This step just reduces the list to words greater than 1 character.

Comment: You don't need to know which ones to exclude, `list_of_words` is the result of `dt['WORD'].str.extractall(r'([A-Z]+)').explode()`